# How to find out whether an entity is detached in JPA / Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to query the JPA **EntityManager** whether a given entity is detached? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779857/how-to-know-if-a-detached-jpa-entity-has-already-been-persisted-or-not) is discussing a similar issue but does not indicate a way to query the JPA **EntityManager** on the detachment status of an entity. I would prefer a JPA way, otherwise Hibernate-specific.

Comment: Did you try [`EntityManager#contains(-)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work. I was looking for something more explicit but the JavaDoc is clear: "Check if the instance is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context."

Comment: Great, so just to keep things clean I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To check if the given entity is managed by the current `PersistenceContext` you can use the [`EntityManager#contains(Object entity)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: -1 This is not a correct answer to the question. Reason: `contains()` will indeed return false if the entity is detached **but it will return false in other cases as well**. By spec, `contains()` returns if the given entity is managed. Detached entities are only one of several reasons that an entity is considered unmanaged.

Comment: As @MRalwasser said: Is this still the case on Hibernate 5? Or ist this changed since the answer was posted? And in which version?

Answer (score 33):

Piotr Nowicki's answer provides a way of determining whether an entity is *managed*. To find out whether an entity has been *detached*, we'd need to know whether it was previously managed (i.e. came from the database, e.g. by being persisted or obtained from a `find` operation). Hibernate doesn't provide an "entity state history" so the short answer is there isn't a 100% reliable way of doing this but the following workaround should be sufficient in most cases:

```
public boolean isDetached(Entity entity) {
    return entity.id != null  // must not be transient
        && !em.contains(entity)  // must not be managed now
        && em.find(Entity.class, entity.id) != null;  // must not have been removed
}
```

The above assumes that `em` is the `EntityManager`, `Entity` is the entity class and has a public `id` field that is a `@GeneratedValue` primary key. (It also assumes that the row with this ID hasn't been removed from the database table by an external process in the time after the entity was detached.)

Comment: In my case the Entity I am trying to update (merge) is always "detached". I ended up wrapping the ".merge()" with a try cacth block, checking on the IllegalArgumentException, which comes up, if it's detached.

Comment: And additionally I don't think an IllegalArgumentException is the right type of Exception for a "object is detached from PersistenceContext" :-)

Comment: @Enerccio The third clause is to find out whether the entity row *still exists in the database* - otherwise it could be a new row that hasn't been persisted. Please see the last sentence of the answer for a caveat about this.

Comment: oh okay, well in my case I needed to find whether entity was deleted